# Ternary operators and variable reassignment in PHP

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I've perused the questions on *ternary operators* vs. *if/else structures*, and while I understand that under normal circumstances there is no performance loss/gain in using ternary operators over if/else structures, I've not seen any mention of this situation. Language specific to PHP (but any language agnostic details are welcome) does the interpreter reassign values in situations like this:

```
$foo = 'bar'
$foo = strlen($foo) > 3 ? substr($foo, 0, 3) : $foo;
```

Since this would evaluate to `$foo = $foo;` is this inefficient, or does the interpreter simply overlook/discard this evaluation?

On a side note, what about:

```
!defined('SECURE') ? exit : null;
```

Comment: My face is going red from the number of answers quoting mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if your first example is inefficient, but it sure is pointless. I still think an if statement is clearer:

```
$foo = 'bar';

if (strlen($foo) > 3)
    $foo = substr($foo, 0, 3);
```

And while the following works, it makes no sense to place `null` at the end because a ternary operator is meant to be used to evaluate expressions/values, but here `null` does nothing other than to prevent a parse error:

```
!defined('SECURE') ? exit : null;
```

More commonly, you would see this, an example of boolean short-circuiting (`or exit` doesn't execute if `SECURE` is not defined, because the `or` conditional expression evaluates to true automatically once at least one condition is found to be true):

```
defined('SECURE') or exit;
```

The point I'm trying to make is this: don't use ternary conditional expressions just because you can.

Comment: Thanks **BoltClock**; It certainly is clearer. I've always wondered why the third expression was necessary when using ternary operators for such circumstances. Perhaps I'm alone, but `$foo = strlen($foo) > 3 ? substr($foo, 0, 3);` seems very readable to me. Boolean short circuiting would be the answer here again, correct?

Comment: @TomcatExodus: Most people reserve short-circuiting for `or die` lines. Sounds just like a real-life death threat :)

Comment: Haha, certainly. The first scenario I pointed out is for my own code refactoring, the second for a colleagues. He's used the `!defined ...` for securing view files from direct access, and full `if` conditions seemed too verbose for him I suppose. While I've accepted the answer as it is clear, any thoughts on the PHP interpreter reassigning values like `$foo = $foo;`?

Comment: I'm not sure what goes on under the hood. Maybe it's smart enough to optimize the line away, maybe it's not.

Comment: @TomcatExodus: By looking at PHP sources, I think I can confirm that PHP will execute the statement `$foo = $foo` anyway, except if `$foo` is an object, the only check happening seems to be when variables are objects. This would not happen in a compiled language however, as the compiler would simply discard the assignment of a variable to itself, because it's useless. ;)

Comment: @BoltClock an old answer that still helps. `but it sure is pointless.` probably saved me hour an hour of life.

Answer (score 0):

In this cases, I use the form presented by BoltClock:

```
if (strlen($foo) > 3) {
    $foo = substr($foo, 0, 3);
}
```

PHP does not implement something more simple to work in this cases, yet :/

Answer (score 0):

The topic that using a ternary here is not optimal has already been covered above. I'm going to address your question about whether it will reassign the value:

This depends on what you call "reassigning". PHP does not optimize, so the `$foo = $foo` will be evaluated. On the other hand this will not cause PHP to copy the value of `$foo` to a new chunk of memory. Probably PHP will just increase the `refcount` on `$foo` and then immediately decrease it (though I'm not sure about the exact implementation details of self-assignment). So, even though PHP will execute the statement, it won't affect performance (unless you choose to write `$foo = $foo` seven million times in your code).

Comment: Thanks for the response **nikic**; For scripts that render to browser, typically I try to remain as efficient as possible, and optimize (via caching mechanisms, etc.) the logic route from request to response. However I do sometimes use PHP for CLI driven scripts, performing complex, high iteration processes (for convenience as I haven't made the transition to Perl) and that's exactly why I was curious. (7 million is high, but certainly not uncommon)

Comment: And even in that case optimizing on the assignment is nonesense. You would for example gain much more by replacing the `strlen` check by `isset($foo[3])` :)

Answer (score 0):

There is always short-circuiting, although as @BoltClock said, an `if` statement is probably more readable in my opinion, and opens the door to `else if` and `else` conditions as well.

```
strlen($foo) > 3 && $foo = substr($foo, 0, 3);
```

The latter statement will only be executed if the former evaluates to TRUE.