# PHP ternary define?

Tags: php, constants

Can someone explain how this define works out:

```
define( 'A_DEFINE', B_VALUE ? 'yes' : 'no' );
```

Seems to be a ternary operator structure there but not quite sure how it all pieces together.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ternary operators and variable reassignment in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641673/ternary-operators-and-variable-reassignment-in-php)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'll bet you can't wait "for the Gold" ;)

Comment: Interestingly, `A_DEFINE` becomes `yes` if `B_VALUE` doesn't exist: https://eval.in/216834

Comment: I've been waiting for such a long time @Fred-ii- ;)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Lordie, you've a ways to go. Using my superpowers wisely ;)

Comment: Ah well, patience...I've got some and I ain't afriad to use it @Fred-ii-

Comment: ...it's a virtue ^^^. If there's another one who agrees with your dupe link, I'll close 'er up; how's that?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: How exactly that question is a duplicate of this one?

Comment: It is a "possible" duplicate @AmalMurali in as much as it describes how the ternary define works.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: While I think that answers the outer question, I don't think it addresses the important point, which is "an uninitialized constant evaluates to true". I think that's probably the OP got confused over this particular statement, but that's just my guess.

Comment: Without further detail from the OP it would be hard to know @AmalMurali

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have to agree on both sides of the coin (lol) not going to pick sides on this one haha Voting as unclear though. For the OP: This is the type of question that could have easily been Google'd. IMHO.

Comment: Regardless of whether it works or not, as a matter of coding practice, I would look upon this line of code with horror. A `define()` is supposed to create a constant. Constants should not have a variable value dependant on other conditions. This is the kind of coding practice that has historically given PHP a reputation for poor quality code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, undefined constants evaluate to true. From the [PHP manual documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php):

> If you use an undefined constant, PHP assumes that you mean the name of the constant itself, just as if you called it as a string (`CONSTANT` vs `"CONSTANT"`). An error of level `E_NOTICE` will be issued when this happens.

You have:

```
define( 'A_DEFINE', B_VALUE ? 'yes' : 'no' );
```

So in the above  statement, this is what happens. If `B_VALUE` evaluates to true (which it does because it's uninitalized), set the value of `A_CONSTANT` to `yes`, else set it to `no`.

```
define('A_DEFINE', B_VALUE ? 'yes' : 'no' );
var_dump(B_VALUE, A_DEFINE); // Just checking what the outputs are
```

The above outputs:

```
string(7) "B_VALUE"
string(3) "yes"
```

Comment: By `A_CONSTANT` do you mean `A_DEFINE`?

Comment: And if B_VALUE _is_ initialized then do you get the same evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming B_VALUE has a boolean value it would mean that if B_VALUE equals true
then A_DEFINE becomes "yes" else it becomes "no".

For example

```
$a = $b ? "yes" : "no";
```

Is the same as

```
if ($b == true) {

    $a = "yes";

} else {

    $a = "no";

}
```

Ternary is just a more readable and very quick way of doing this.

Hope this helps!